# Installing latest texlive to a different installation location

Tags: texlive

I have the latest texlive installation but getting the error listed below.  How can I  choose a different installation location?

```
 *** WARNING ****************************************************
The installation requires 7336M of disk space
but only 809M is available.

You probably want to either clean up the destination filesystem,
or choose a different installation location,
or reduce what gets installed.
```

Comment: Please refer to the [texlive installation guide](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-250003.2.3).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `I have the latest texlive installation but getting the error listed below. How can I choose a different installation location?` Are you trying to install on a different location? The installer has an interface for that. But you have to tell it where to install and make sure it is a place on your computer that has sufficient space.

Comment: Yes, trying to install on a different location.

Comment: As mentioned it is part of the installer.

Comment: Will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

The texlive installer has an interface for inputting the different install location the user would like to use.